# xpath: extract data from a node

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, xpathnavigator

I am trying to extra some data from a webpage. the structure of the webpage is as below

```
<li id="yui_3_4_1_1_1326860702769_9706">
<span id="yui_3_4_1_1_1326860702769_9705">Sales rank: </span>
2
</li>
```

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/enders-game-orson-scott-card/1100353963?ean=9781429963930

I need to extract value "2" from above and identifier has to be "Sales rank"

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//descendant::*[@class='product-details box']/ul/li[span='Sales rank: ']/text()
```

Comment: This selects more than one node -- be aware of the whitespace-only text nodes.

Comment: awesome this works : query("//descendant::*[@class='product-details box']/ul/li[span='Sales rank: ']/text()")->item(0)->nodeValue;

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
//div[@class="product-details"]/ul/li[9]
```

Not tested though.

Comment: the issue is that it is not always 9th element :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//li[@id='yui_3_4_1_1_1326860702769_9706']
    /span[. = 'Sales rank: ']
      /following-sibling::text()[1]
```

This selects the first following-sibling text node of any `span` element with string value `'Sales rank: '`, that is a child of any `li` element whose `id` attribute has the value of `'yui_3_4_1_1_1326860702769_9706'` .

Comment: thanks Dimitre. however "yui_3_4_1_1_1326860702769_9706" is a dynamically generated number for thse sections and thus can not use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this， if any question, please let me know

```
`//li[@id]/*[contains(text(), 'Sales rank')]/following-sibling::node()[1]`
```